# Parsing XML in iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, nsxmlparser, xmppframework

I received the following IQ in `- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq`

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client'
    type='result'
    to='abc@xyz/6cbb843f'>
<questions>
<question id='56'
          text='Favorite Food'>
<option id='1'>
chinese
</option>
<option id='2'>
indian
</option>
<option id='3'>
thai
</option>
</question>
<question id='57'
          text='Music'>
<option id='4'>
eastern
</option>
<option id='5'>
pop
</option>
<option id='6'>
classical
</option>
</question>
<question id='58'
          text='Movies/TV Shows'/>
</questions>
</iq>
```

and I want to retrieve the questions and their options from the above IQ in iOS. I tried the below code but it only give me the questions and I'm unable to retrieve their options. Please help.

```
NSXMLElement *Questions = [iq elementForName:@"questions"];
            NSArray *questions = [Questions elementsForName: @"question"];

            NSLog(@"Questions in IQ %@ are: %@", [iq attributeStringValueForName:@"questions"], questions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You custom XML is not well-formed, `questions` should be bound to some namespace, e.g.
   <questions xmlns="my:questions:namespace">... </questions>
   all child elements will be treated as elements from `my:questions:namespace` and XML will be well-formed.
2. You confused with elements and attributes, `question` is a child element of `questions`, but `text` is an attribute of `question` and "Favorite food" is the string value of `text` attribute of the `question` element with `id`=56. And `option` is a child element of `question`. So, to enumerate questions and answers, try:

   ```
   NSXMLElement *questions = [iq elementForName:@"questions"];
   NSArray *questionsArray = [questions elementsForName: @"question"];
   for (id question in questionsArray) {
       NSLog(@"Question '%@':", [question attributeStringValueForName:@"text"]);
       for (id option in [question elementsForName:@"option"]) {
           NSLog(@"option: %@", [option stringValue])
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: great, I'm receiving the IQ in "didReceiveIQ" and I want to show these questions in the view controller other than app delegate. Is this possible to perform the above functionality of retrieving question and options in another view controller? If yes, than could you please suggest me a solution.

Comment: `didReceiveIQ` is method  of the `XMPPStreamDelegate` protocol, implement it in your view controller and add that controller to XMPPStream delegates list with `[xmppStream addDelegate:...]`.

Comment: I'm sending IQ's from several controllers where necessary and receiving their responses in didReceiveIQ in AppDelegate. I'm sorry if this sounds dumb as I'm new to XMPP framework. Do you mean that every controller will implement its own didReceiveIQ method?

Comment: I tried the below code in AppDelegate

`- (void)setupStream 
{
    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];

    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [XMPPStream addDelegate:ViewController];

}`

but it is not working.

Comment: In case of `XMPPIQ` packet - the only single delegate should process response and return `YES` if packet was handled, or `NO` if other delegates should process it.
So you should process your `questions` response in a single delegate, save in your own structure and pass to view controller if needed

Comment: Currently I'm handling questions response in AppDelegate and they are received in `didReceiveIQ`. I'll store the response in an array and shall pass them to the controller. Please correct me if that is the wrong approach. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also you can store them in Core Data and fetch from your view controller, etc.

Comment: In fact, handling in AppDelegate was made as simple example, every standard extension handler in XMPPramework subclassing special XMPPModule interface to be implemented as "plugin" to XMPPStream, which you need just `activate`, and XMPPCoreDataStorage interface, if your xmpp extension needs to save some data and accessed by others. So you can made your XMPPQuestions interface and create XMPPQuestionCoreDataStorageObject to consistence with other XMPPFramework modules.

Comment: How can we get the id's of the questions and options in an array from the code that you have mentioned above. I tried `id question in questionsArray` but its not working. Please help

Comment: for (id question in questionArray) {NSLog(@"%@", [question attributeStringValueForName:@"id"])}

Comment: For sending answers back I need to send xml like this
if answer is provided by options then it is optionid - otherwise text in the answer tag
`<iq type="set">
<questions xmlns="profile">
<question id="59">
<answer optionid="">I am passionate</answer>
</question>
</questions>
</iq>` I tried the below code for this but not working:

Comment: How to produce `<answer optionid="">I am passionate</answer>`?

Comment: I added this and is working now `DDXMLElement *childQueryAns = [DDXMLNode elementWithName:@"answer" stringValue:@"I'm passionate"];` :)

Comment: I want to parse the xml. Unable to get user type. `<iq xmlns='jabber:client'
            type='result'
            to='abc@xyz-system/e365f044'>
            <service xmlns='service'>
            <user>
            <usertype>
            registered
            </usertype>
            </user>
            </service>
            </iq>`